# How do I display a JLabel over a JButton

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, jlabel

[I can see the button and when I get rid of the button, I can see the JLabel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sm0C9.png)I'm using the Eclipse IDE and I'm trying to have a JLabel display over a JButton.

I already tried creating my JLabel above my JButton, still doesn't work

Comment: Don't post images of code. Post the actual formatted code with your question. *I want a label to display over the button* - Why? It looks to me like all you need to do is change the text of the button when you click on it.

Comment: `jButton1.setVisible(false);`. When you want to display the button again: `jButton1.setVisible(true);`.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle has a helpful tutorial, [Creating a GUI With Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html).  Skip the Learning Swing with the NetBeans IDE section.  Pay particular attention to the [Laying Out Components Within a Container](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) section.

Since you posted an image of your code fragment, I created the following GUI.

[image: Example]

I should post an image of the code, but I'm going to be nice and post the complete runnable code.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class JLabelOverJButtonGUI implements Runnable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new JLabelOverJButtonGUI());
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.add(createMainPanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private JPanel createMainPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1, 5, 5));
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(0, 5, 5, 5));

        JLabel label = new JLabel("Label");
        panel.add(label);

        JButton button = new JButton("Button");
        panel.add(button);

        return panel;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you, although my question was how would I display a JLable's text over a JButton. When looking at the code segment you have given me, it creates a label and button. I want a label to display over the button

Comment: @Hazrd: I don't understand your comment.  The label displays over the button.